# update panel not working with toolkitScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used `ajaxControl` toolkits control now I want to use update panel I have added it but it is not working it will work on `scriptManager` but other controls of `ajaxcontrol` toolkits not working.

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide additional details and the code that isn't working.
Are your script manager and update panel inside of a form tag?
What version of the .net framework are you using?
The easiest way for to get help would be by posting the code that isn't working and then explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: It would help to give us some sample code, somewhere where it isn't working, otherwise there isn't really much to go on.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this by:

1. Setting the UpdatePanel's UpdateMode property to Conditional.
2. Setting the UpdatePanel's ChildrenAsTriggers property to false.
3. Defining AsyncPostBackTriggers for the UpdatePanel.

   ```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="x" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
    ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
   <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="a" EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="b" EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="c" EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
   </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
    Some Content
   </ContentTemplate>
   ```

I verified by checking the value of the ScriptManager's IsInAsyncPostBack property.

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack
```